# Spark Dataframe schema definition using reflection with case classes and column name aliases

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, reflection, case-class

I ran into a little problem with my Spark Scala script. Basically I have raw data which I am doing aggregations on and after grouping and counting etc I want to save the output to a specific JSON format.

**EDIT:**

I tried to simplify the question and rewrote it:

When I select data from the source dataframe with an `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]` where the column names have aliases, then using column names (or indeed indices) as variables when trying to map the rows to a case class, then I get a "Task not serializable" exception.

```
var dm = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq((1,"James"),(2,"Anna"))).toDF("id", "name")

val cl = dm.columns
val cl2 = cl.map(name => col(name).as(name.capitalize))
val dm2 = dm.select(cl2:_*)
val n = "Name"
case class Result(Name:String)
val r = dm2.map(row => Result(row.getAs(n))).toDF
```

And the second part or the question, I actually need the final schema to be an array of these `Result` class objects. I still haven't figured out, how to do this as well. The expected result should have a schema like that:

```
    case class Test(var FilteredStatistics: Array[Result])
    val t = Test(Array(Result("Anna"), Result("James")))

    val t2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(t)).toDF

    scala> t2.printSchema
    root
     |-- FilteredStatistics: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

**TL;DR**:

1. How to map dataframe rows to a case class object when dataframe columns have aliases and variables are used for column names?
2. How to add these case class objects to an array?

Comment: the serialization issue doesn't reproduce - I copied all your code and it works well for me. Looks like somewhere in your code (not pasted here?) you are using a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` object within a case class used in a DataFrame or in a transformation that is serialized and sent to workers...

Comment: BTW - one of us is probably lost in the details of this very elaborate question... try to _minimize_ it (a lot) - find the simplest example that reproduces the issue (and ask the other question separately after similar minimalization)

Comment: one fix to try for your Serialization problem...  `class Result(???) extends Serializable; object Result { def apply(r: Row): Result = r match { ??? } }`  then use pattern matching on r to deal with the variety of formats you might have in your DF.  it's often a problem when you try to apply a class to part of a row, but if you create a class that you can map the entire row...    `DF.map(Result)` may then work.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811) for more help understanding Task Not Serializable issues.

Comment: @TzachZohar Maybe it's an issue of enviroment? I am using Spark on AWS EMR clusters, currently started a clean emr-4.6.0 with Spark 1.6.1 and copied only the code I shared here and I still got the serialization error. And that was me already trying to minimize it, actual implementation is even more complex. The only place currently where the `Column` is used, is creating a map in step 3. But I can't use a string Seq there, because with strings, groupBy works only like this: `(col1: String,cols: String*)`. But I edited the question with the simplest version of the question.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the question - much better now! I can reproduce the issue now, await an answer...

Comment: As for your second question - it's better to make it a separate post

Comment: @TzachZohar Thanks! I will get around to trying your solution soon. As for the second part, I thought about making a separate question about it as well.

Comment: @kmh would this solution work with n amount of columns? And I would just need to handle the primitive types like int, double, string, long etc? Or should I create a new dataframe with the specific columns I need?

Answer (score 0):

**Serialization Issue**: the problem here is the `val n = "Name"`: it is used inside an anonymous function passed into an RDD transformation (`dm2.map(...)`), which makes Spark close over that variable *and the scope containing it*, which also includes `cl2` which has the type `Array[Column]`, hence it isn't serializable.

The solution is simple - either inline `n` (to get `dm2.map(row => Result(row.getAs("Name")))`), or place it in a Serializable context (an object or a class that doesn't contain any non-serializable members).

Comment: Okay, I am still having some difficulties. I don't want to do it inline as I declare the column names in one place and then use them throughout the code. I don't want to duplicate them because then I would have to change them in multiple places. But did you mean that I should create an object or a class for holding the necessary variables? I tried `object Params extends Serializable { val name = "Name" }` and `case class Params(name:String)` (case class was supposed to be serializable by default) and using `Params.name` inside the getAs and that didn't help. Sorry if I missed something obvious

Comment: If the object isn't nested in any other class - it should work (works for me...). Note that when you create objects in *spark-shell* they are actually nested in the object that encapsulates the entire shell code, so it might not work there (I think)